# Which Babylon 5 episode introduced the control creatures?

Tags: episode-identification, babylon-5

I know:

- The episode is in season 4
- It takes place on Mars
- During this episode, Marcus and Doctor Franklin are taking a shuttle to mars, and encounter someone who they are suspicious of at first, but then learn that they are their contact from the Mars Resistance
- It has the Shadow control creatures (I believe it's the only episode in the season that has them) and it turns out that the contact from the Mars resistance is being controlled by them and has to commit suicide to break free from their control

Which episode am I thinking of?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Racing Mars](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Racing_Mars) (Season 4, Episode 10) is the first *chronological* in-universe appearance of a [Keeper](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Keeper), although we do see elderly Londo's in *[War Without End, Part II](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/War_Without_End,_Part_II)* (Season 3, Episode 17) in the previous season.

Captain Jack has been infected with one in order to direct him to kill Number One.

Comment: Isn't _[War Without End, Part II](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/War_Without_End,_Part_II)_ the first appearance of a Keeper?

Comment: @Anonymous - Yes, that's my bad. I've edited to reflect that it was the earliest use of one chronologically. First Jack, then Milo Virini, then Londo Mollari then David Sheridan II.